Blocked customer in the Erlang loss system
Consider an M/M/n loss system, called system $A$. When a customer is blocked by system $A$, i.e., no available units in system $A$, she will enter another system, called system $B$. I wonder what the arrival pattern of system $B$ is.
My thought: Suppose the arrival rate of system $A$ is $\lambda$, and the blocking probability of system $A$ is $Q$. It is intuitive that the arrival pattern of system $B$ is Poisson arrival with rate $\lambda Q$. Is there any simple argument can prove this statement?

But, if seems that if we check it by the definition of Poisson arrival, it does not satisfy the independent increments.
